# Openvino does not detect Intel GPU in Ubuntu Docker

Tags: docker, gpu, intel, inference, openvino

I am pretty new to this Openvino and Intel GPU world, I have pulled openvino/openvino_tensorflow_ubuntu18_runtime:2.0.0 docker image and when I run the OpenVINO_TensorFlow_classification_example.ipynb it only sees "CPU" when listing backends.

However, when running `lspci -nn -s 0:002.0` inside the docker container it outputs:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0412] (rev 06)
```

I have tried to run a simpler python script to only print the openvino backends but I keep getting only the CPU backend.

What am I missing here? Is my iGPU not compatible with OpenVino? Am I missing some driver or some kind of configuration?

My native OS is Debian11.

**EDIT:**

Indeed I ran the docker container with the iGPU command in the image documentation as Peh_Intel suggests. However, I keep getting only the CPU backend. There is an screenshot of terminal and jupyter notebook outputs below.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmcFg.png)

Answer (score 1):

GPU is not available in the container by default. Attach it to the container.

Launch the Jupyter server with iGPU access:

```
docker run -it --rm \

  -p 8888:8888 \

  --device-cgroup-rule='c 189:* rmw' \

  --device /dev/dri:/dev/dri \

  openvino/openvino_tensorflow_ubuntu18_runtime:2.0.0
```

Comment: Can refer to https://hub.docker.com/r/openvino/openvino_tensorflow_ubuntu18_runtime and 
https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_docker_linux.html#running-the-image-on-gpu

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I was already running the container with this command but only getting the CPU backend, please see the edited post.